# R table data and create additional columns

Tags: r, multiple-columns

I have data as below.

```
A=c(rep("x",3),rep("Y",2),rep("Z",3))

B=c(0,1,0,1,1,0,0,0)

new=data.frame(A,B)
```

I want to create one column -`modified_zip` as below

1. Look at count of unique values in column A. example - X=3, Y=2, Z=3
2. for each unique value in column A, find sum of column B. for example when column A has x, column B sum is 1. when column A has z, column B sum is 0
3. Divide calculation 1 by calculation 2 and find %. X=1/3,Y=2/2,Z=0/3
4. create a new column that will have below values

   •   if calculation 1 is above 100 and calculation 3 is above 65% then `modified_zip` will have value `65%above100`

   •   if calculation 1 is above 100 and calculation 3 is less than 35% then `modified_zip` will have value `35%above100`

   •   if calculation 1 is above 100 and calculation 3 is between 35% to 65 then `modified_zip` will have value `otherabove100`

   •   if calculation 1 is between 50 to 100 and calculation 3 is above 65% then `modified_zip` will have value `65%between50and100`

   •   if calculation 1 is between 50 to 100 and calculation 3 is below 35% then `modified_zip` will have value `35%between50and100`

   •   if calculation 1 is between 50 to 100 and calculation 3 is between 35% and 65% then `modified_zip` will have value `otherbetween50and100`

   •   if calculation 1 is between 10 to 50 and calculation 3 is above 65% then `modified_zip` will have value `65%between10and50`

   •   if calculation 1 is between 10 to 50 and calculation 3 is below 35% then `modified_zip` will have value `35%between10and50`

   •   if calculation 1 is between 10 to 50 and calculation 3 is between 35% and 65% then `modified_zip` will have value `otherbetween10and50`

   •   if calculation 1 is below 10 then `modified_zip` will have value `smallnumber`

I tried to use `table` command but dont know how to work with % and counts, both

Comment: Which of the steps is giving you problems? For example (1 and 2) seem to be one problem, while 3, 4 are separate problems. I imagine you will be able to do (3, 4) yourself if you had the output of (1, 2)? What are "calculation 1", "calculation 2", "Cclculation 3"? Can you narrow down the specific thing that is your problem and show us what you have tried? The question is too broad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#Look at count of unique values in column 
library(sqldf)
sqldf("select A, count(A) from new group by A")

#for each unique value in column A, find sum of column B. 
sqldf("select A, count(A), sum(B) as sumB from new group by A")

# Divide calculation 1 by calculation 2
new1      <- sqldf("select A, count(A), sum(B) as sumB from new group by A")
new1$calc <- new1$`count(A)`/new1$sumB
new1$calc[is.infinite(new1$calc)] <- 0
new1$calc <- new1$calc*100
```

You have a very long list of rules there and almost none of them apply to your example because your highest Calculation 1 is 3, but when you know how to do 1 you know how to do all of them, so I will give you 1 example:

```
#create a new column that will have below values
new1$modified_zip <- NA
new1$modified_zip[new1$`count(A)` > 100 & new1$calc > 65] <- "65%above100"
```

Answer (score 3):

Another way, using `data.table'

```
library( data.table )
setDT(new)
```

The `by` parameter will tell `data.table` to calculate separately for every unique value of "A"

```
new[ , calc1 := sum( B ), by = A ]
```

`.N` is a preset value for the number of rows/observations/... in the table (or the given `by` set)

```
new[ , calc2 := B / .N, by = A ]
```

Now add the character column you wanted, and start filling the subsets. One example here, since as @Hack-R says, once you know how to do one, you know how to do them all:

```
new[ , modified_zip := as.character( NA ) ]
new[ calc1 > 100 & calc2 > 0.65, modified_zip := "65%above100" ]
```

Comment: thanks for the answer. But i chose the sqldf answer as the official answer as it was easier for me to use..